# Using jQuery to sum values from a couple text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a couple of text inputs and I would like to compute the sum of the values in another input. This must happen on the fly, as soon as the user enters a value in one of the inputs. I'm planning to use jQuery for this, and I would like to add a class name for each input, something like class="input1", class="input2" and so on.

My problem is that I don't know to add all those values, and given the fact that I have over 50 inputs, I don't want to "add them by hand".

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Why increment the number on the classes, just give all the inputs the same class, it makes selecting them easier and the selector will perform much faster?

Comment: @Psyche - I agree with Jasper - if making all the inputs you want summed have the same class name is possible, that will definitely make things cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decorate all of the inputs you want added together with classes of `input1`, `input2`, and so on, this will get the sum of the current values in all those inputs

```
var sum = 0;

$("input[class *= 'input']").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
});
```

Then naturally if you want to put this value in an input of id `destination`

```
$("#destination").val(sum);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qztcU/)

**EDIT**

If you want this to run whenever any of these textboxes are *changed*, then you can put this in a change event handler

```
$(document).on("change", "input[class *= 'input']", function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input[class *= 'input']").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });

    $("#destination").val(sum);
});
```

Here's that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qztcU/1/)

**EDIT**

Per Jaspers comment, if you know that `input1`, `input2`, etc, will *always* be the first class on your inputs, ie, you'll *never* do

```
<input class='someNewClass input1'
```

then you could

```
$("input[class ^= 'input']").each(function(){
```

`^=` means starts with, while  `*=` means contains anywhere.

Comment: Wouldn't `[class ^= 'input']` be a bit more appropriate, to match the beginning of the string rather than anywhere in the string?

Comment: @Jasper - potentially, yes.  But if OP ever decides to do `<input class='someNewClass input1'` that would break

Comment: @AdamRackis, I made a little edit to the post because I would like to sum to be computed on the fly, after the user enters a value in one of those inputs.

Comment: @Psyche Are you using jquery 1.7?

Comment: @Psyche - here's the old-school way to do it for older jQuery versions   `$(document).delegate("input[class *= 'input']", "change", function() {...`

Comment: @AdamRackis, I have updated to jQuery 1.7.1. Now I don't get any error, but it's not working.

Comment: @Psyche - well I put up the fiddle, which does work - so look closely at the code there and see what's different.

Comment: Silly me, class/id confusion. Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to trigger the function onkeydown(I tried it but it doesn't work corectly)

Answer (score 1):

give them a common name and you need to parse the value since it will be text initially

```
var result= 0;

$("input[name='sum']").each(function(){
    result = result + parseInt($(this).val(),10);
});
```

Comment: I'll +1 this if you add a radix parameter to your parseInt call.

Comment: i was thinking while typing but then missed it. Thanks :)